# Concatenate two columns in HANA database

Tags: sql-server, hana

Please give me an advice to convert below MSSQL VIEW to HANA VIEW

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewSample]
AS
SELECT [column1] + ' / ' + [column2] AS CollectionLabel
FROM [dbo].[T1] T1
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[T2] T2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what problem? what error do you get?

Comment: read the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d5fa9b75191014a33eee92692f1702/content.htm?frameset=/en/20/fcf24075191014a89e9dc7b8408b26/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/plain.htm&node_id=210), maybe. what's exactly the issue?

Comment: This syntax is not correct in HANA database. error is  "invalid number: ' / ' "

Comment: the error message is an important part of the problem that must be in the question. the message itself is pretty clear: the `+` operator is trying to 'sum' the values you feed to it and the value '/' is not a number. you have to find how data conversion/casting is performed or use a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `CONCAT` twice?

```
CREATE VIEW "dbo"."ViewSample"
    AS
    SELECT CONCAT("column1", CONCAT(' / ', "column2")) AS CollectionLabel
    FROM "dbo"."T1" T1
    CROSS JOIN "dbo"."T2" T2
```

Answer (score 10):

There is also a concat operator which allows you to do that (||)

```
CREATE VIEW "dbo"."ViewSample"
    AS
    SELECT "column1" || ' / ' || "column2" AS CollectionLabel
    FROM "dbo"."T1" T1
    CROSS JOIN "dbo"."T2" T2
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use '||' to concatenate string and columns.

Suppose that you need a full name of person, and in your table has two columns, the NAME and LAST_NAME.

```
SELECT NAME||' '||LAST_NAME FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewSample]
AS
SELECT [column1] || ' ' || [column2] AS CollectionLabel
FROM [dbo].[T1] T1
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[T2] T2
```

> You should use '||' for concatenation